# Chart.js - Ajax response not accept

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

chart.js not accept ajax post - json respose.i couldn't solve it yet.please help..
https://prnt.sc/spt4p3
https://prnt.sc/spt6j0

my json file is:

```
[{"DAYS":"01.05.2020","VALUES":"0"},{"DAYS":"02.05.2020","VALUES":"0"},{"DAYS":"03.05.2020","VALUES":"0"},{"DAYS":"04.05.2020","VALUES":"0"},{"DAYS":"05.05.2020","VALUES":"0"},{"DAYS":"06.05.2020","VALUES":"0"},]
```

---

javascript file is:

```
                var days = [];
                var values=[];
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'class/report/daily_report.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'reload': 'renew', 'type': 'rep_1'},
                    success: function (response) {
                        var jsonARR =$.parseJSON(response);
                        var k=0;
                        for ( var key in jsonARR ) {
                            days[k]=jsonARR[key]["DAYS"];
                            values[k]=parseInt(jsonARR[key]["VALUES"]);
                            k++;
                        }

                    }
                });
                var a = {
                    labels: days,
                    datasets: [{
                        backgroundColor: KTApp.getStateColor("danger"),
                        data: values
                    }]
                };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remind that [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) makes an asynchronous HTTP request. In you code however, you create the chart even before ans answer from that request is received.

The problem can be solved by moving the code responsible for chart creation inside the `$.ajax()` block as shown below.

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(response) {
    var jsonARR = $.parseJSON(response);
    var k = 0;
    for (var key in jsonARR) {
      days[k] = jsonARR[key]["DAYS"];
      values[k] = parseInt(jsonARR[key]["VALUES"]);
      k++;
    };
    var a = {
      labels: days,
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: KTApp.getStateColor("danger"),
        data: values
      }]
    };
    new Chart(...);
  });
```